# Identity provider implementation of opensaml 2.0

Tags: saml

We need to implement Identity provider implementation of opensaml2.0 for our project. Is there anybody has idea on how to start with...
Your response is much  appreciated...

Answer (score 5):

I am currently using [OpenSAML](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/OpenSAML/Home/) by "Internet2".  I don't know much about them but we've been using their libraries for a while without any problems.  The documentation on the OpenSAML1 version are non-existent ... but support for OpenSAML2 is much better.

You may also find some of the commercial product useful (taken from their site):

- [Shibboleth](http://shibboleth.internet2.edu/)
- [Globus Toolkit](http://www.globus.org/toolkit/)
- [gLite](http://glite.web.cern.ch/glite/)
- [VO Privilege Project](http://www.fnal.gov/docs/products/voprivilege/)
- [Clarity Security's SSO Toolkit](http://code.crt.realtors.org/projects/websso)
- [VOMS](https://twiki.cnaf.infn.it/cgi-bin/twiki/view/VOMS/WebHome)
- [JBoss](http://labs.jboss.com/)
- [CAS](http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/downloads/index.html)
- [OpenPermis](http://www.openpermis.org/)
- [Apache Rampart](http://ws.apache.org/rampart)
- [OLAT](http://www.olat.org/website/en/html/index.html)
- [eduGAIN](http://www.edugain.org/)
- [openLiberty Wakame](http://www.openliberty.org/)
- [OpenASelect](http://www.openaselect.org/)

Answer (score 4):

Here are two great links that helped me get started (these are now considered deprecated with respect to Google Apps which has moved to a newer standard)

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation

and

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation_web

Comment: I'm currently building a SAML Service provider.

Comment: Both links appear to be broken now.

Comment: @Tom, fixed the links :)