# Workaround to share session cookie between two domains in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, session, tomcat, cookies

I have a website under a domain called `www.example.com.br`. And my server is set to work with **cookie session tracking mode**.

```
getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig().setDomain(".example.com.br");
getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig().setPath("/");
```

But now I'm introducing an english version of the website under www.example.com, because for Google and SEO techniques it's better to have different domains instead of a subdomain.

I found a lot of questions in Stack Overflow about this, and I know it's impossible for a lot of security reasons.

But isn't there anyway to tell Tomcat to work with a cookie domain `.example.com.br` if the URL has `.com.br` and `.example.com` if the URL has `.com`? I don't need to share session information... ie: **the user may have to login again if he changes the domain.** I'm not worried about it. The problem is that no information on the `.com` version is been stored at all, because the cookie is set to `.com.br` version.

Isn't there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is user's browser that decides whether to send the cookie with the request or not. Web server (Tomcat, in your case) does not have any say in that decision. What you are asking for explicitly forbidden. For example, [RFC2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) says:

> A user agent should make every attempt to prevent the sharing of
> session information between hosts that are in different domains.

The best recommendation I can make is to make your session management (login, logout, ...) work off a single domain, regardless of what domain user originally accessed.

Comment: Hi Marko, thanks in advance. Do you have any reading to recommend me about how to do this session management work off a single domain?

Comment: It really depends on the type of application and the frameworks you are using. Maybe you could structure your application in a way that all authenticated requests go to example.com domain. If user goes to example.com.br, you could redirect requests to example.com and set parameter specifying that brazilian locale should be used. Like I said, details depend heavily on your use case, so, it's difficult to give any useful advice.

Comment: By the way, maybe some of the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950023/how-to-implement-sso-on-existing-tomcat-web-application) question can help or give you some new ideas.

Comment: Thank you guys, but the solution was, instad of using a new domain like example.com, I have to create a subdomain like english.example.com.br, and all requests to example.com redirect to that subdomain. My main concern is about SEO strategies, so, using a Locale change on session is not an option for us.