# Java SSO: Prompting user and password

Tags: java, active-directory, spnego, waffle

I'm trying to do SSO with java. I have waffle and SPNEGO, both works perfectly, but just if i use localhost on the browser, if i use ip or pc-name, he prompt the browser, any tips?

I'm using a Windows Server 2012, running tomcat, java 1.8, and i'm using a windows 8 VM to acess the server to use the webapp(wich is an example of the SPNEGO(hello_spnego). I've already configured the web browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Implement SSO on existing tomcat web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950023/how-to-implement-sso-on-existing-tomcat-web-application)

Comment: Not a duplicate